# How to make functions

Tags: macros, math-operators

I’m not entirely sure here what terminology I should exactly be using, but let me illustrate a use case.

```
...
\matr{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}
...
```

to replace this:

```
...
$\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{matrix}\right]$
...
```

How would I go about defining `\matr{...}`?

Comment: @doncherry: Other unnecessary edited stuffs were done just for passing the 6-character constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing to it, really :)

For more details on how to define custom macros in LaTeX, have a look at [this section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands) of the LaTeX wikibook.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\matr[1]
{%
  \ensuremath
  {
    \begin{bmatrix}
      #1
    \end{bmatrix}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\matr{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `bmatrix`?

Comment: @egreg You're absolutely right.

Comment: I'd suggest you encase the argument of `\matr` in an `\ensuremath` statement instead of a pair of `$` text-mode/inline-math switches. That way, the command `\matr` will work equally well in text mode, inline math mode, and display math mode...

Comment: @Mico That's a good idea.